# How to set nested recycler views adapters when we use data binding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-databinding

I have a nested recycler view(a parent and several childs), I also use data binding.

The problem is that, since the adapter for nested recyclers is different, I do not know how to set the nested recyclers adaptor in Kotlin or Java.

[image]

In case I don't want to use data binding, the solution in this [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/easily-adding-nested-recycler-view-in-android-a7e9f7f04047) is working fine.

Thanks

Comment: Check if my answer solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Databinding is data driving，so you can place the child adapter in the parent model, and define a databinding adapter for recyclerview.

```
pulic class ParentModel
{
    private ChildAdapter childAdapter;
}
```

```
public class DataBindingAdapters
{
    @BindingAdapter({"adapter"})
    public void setRecyclerViewAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView, ChildAdapter childAdapter)
    {
        recyclerView.serAdapter(childAdapter);
    }
}
```

```
<recyclerView
    app:adapter="@{model.childAdapter}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set `RecyclerView` adapter using android data binding.

***Layout code:***

*Data part:*

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="adapter"
        type="com.app.adapter.RecyclerViewAdapter" />
</data>
```

*Recyclerview Layout:*

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:adapter="@{adapter}"
  app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
  android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

***Java file: DataBindingAdapters.java***

```
public class DataBindingAdapters {

    @BindingAdapter({"adapter"})
    public static void setRecyclerViewAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter) {

        recyclerView.setAdapter(RecyclerViewAdapter);
    }
}
```

***Note:***
1. `setRecyclerViewAdapter`must be static to avoid this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45933481).
2. In my code `RecyclerViewAdapter` is the custom recyclerview adapter.
3. Set `LayoutManager` either in code or in layout file, but not in both.(Xml would be preferred when using android data binding)
4. Refer this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679776/how-to-set-recyclerview-applayoutmanager-from-xml) for queries related to the layout manager like how to set for androidX, orientation, gridview rows, etc.